# Out of the box features of SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I am new in SharePoint and I want to know out of the box features of SharePoint 2013.

Please provide full details of out of the box features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please refer the below  msdn link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1a9a51b6-b66f-4a9a-83bb-21b2e3cca8dd/learn-sharepoint-out-of-the-box-features?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Here is the list of all OOBT features

Content Editor:
This web part allows content authors to insert arbitrary content into a web part zone. This gives additional flexibility, but can also be a problem because there is no control over the content that editors can insert into pages.

HTML Form:
Renders simple HTML form controls which can be connected to other web parts.

Image Viewer:
Allows an editor to show an image.

Media:
Shows embedded media (audio or video) in the page.

Page Viewer:
Embeds another web page within the page using an IFRAME element.

Silverlight:
Shows a Silverlight embedded client-side application.

Business Data Actions:
Shows a list of actions from the Business Data Catalog.

Business Data Catalog Filter:
Allows you to choose one entity from the BCS and specify value column and description column.

Choice Filter:
Allows you to specify values in the tool pane of the Web Part. Users select one of the values from a drop-down menu that appears on the page.

SharePoint List Filter:
Point to a SharePoint list and the specify the value of a column, such as title, description or document type. Users can browse to the list and choose from the item type you specify.

SQL Server Analysis Services Filter:
Allows you to select a data connection from a Web Part on the current page or from a SharePoint Data Connection library or Office Data Connection library. You can then specify a dimension and hierarchy in order to display data from your SQL Server Analysis Services cubes.

Current User Filter:
Uses either the current user’s login name or a selected profile property. Provides a query string parameter.

Query String Filter:
Passes a parameter you specify in the query string.

Page Field Filter:
Value of a column on the list row that the current page is associated with

Date Filter:
Users are able to pick a date from a drop-down calendar or enter a mm/dd/yyyy value into the edit box.

Text Filter:
Require users to enter text or use a default value.

Chart:
A very powerful web part that displays a chart based on list contents.

Business Data Item:
Shows a single item from a data source in the Business Data Catalog.

Business Data Item Builder:
Create an item from query string parameters and provides it as a connection to other Web Parts.

Business Data List:
Show a list of items from a data source in the Business Data Catalog.

Business Data Related List:
Show a list of items related to one or more parent items from the Business Data Catalog.

Key Performance Indicators (Status List):
Shows a Key Performance Indicator status list. The KPI list contains individual status indicators based on information derived from other SharePoint lists or data sources.

KPI Details:
Shows a detailed view of a single Key Performance Indicator status item.

Visio Web Access:
Surfaces content from Visio diagrams (.vdw files).

Content Query:
One of the most heavily used web parts. Allows you to aggregate content in, for example, a home page or hub page. This web part is not able to aggregate content across site collection boundaries. Dependent on the publishing feature to be activated.

SAP iView:
Used to display SAP data in SharePoint sites.

Picture Library Slideshow:
Displays a slideshow of images from a picture library.

RSS Viewer:
Renders the contents of an RSS feed, typically from an external source.

What's Popular:
Uses web analytics to show the most viewed content, popular search queries or search results.

XML Viewer:
Takes an XML input and transforms it using XSLT.

Document ID Lookup:
Shows an input box where a user can enter a Document ID and navigate to the target document.

Document Set Contents:
Shows the contents of a document set.

Document Set Properties:
Shows the properties of a document set.

Relevant Documents:
Shows documents that are relevant to the current user. Installed with Document Centre and MySites.

Categories:
Shows categories derived from the site directory. (Provided for backwards compatibility).

Site Aggregator:
Show chosen sites

Sites in Category:
Show sites from a specified category.

Summary Links:
Allow publishing authors to create lists of links.

Table of Contents:
Representation of the site's navigation heirarchy.

Tag Cloud:
Shows a tag cloud of enterprise tags with relative importance, based on usage within the organization.

Excel Web Access:
Surfaces Excel data in a web page, acting as a client to Excel Services.

InfoPath Form
Shows a browser-enabled InfoPath form.

Contact Details:
Shows contact details for the user on a My Site page.

Site Users:
Shows a list of site user and whether they are online.

User Tasks:
Shows tasks assigned to the current user.

PerformancePoint Filter:
Displays filters for use in a PerformancePoint dashboard application.

PerformancePoint Report Viewer:
Displays a PerformancePoint report in various formats including charts, grids, maps, etc.

PerformancePoint Scorecard:
Displays a PerformancePoint sorecard​.

PerformancePoint Stack Selector:
Displays a PerformancePoint Stack Selector to allow users to select and stack individual components of the PerformancePoint dashboard.

Advanced Search Box:
Show parameterized search options based on properties and combinations of words.

Federated Results:
Show search results from an external search provider that supports standard search results formats.

People Refinement Panel:
Search refiner panel for people search results. Activate the Search Server Web Part feature.

People Search Box:
Search input box to find people (users).

People Search Core Results:
Shows people search results and properties.

Refinement Panel:
General purpose search refiner panel. Activate the Search Server Web Part feature.

Related Queries:
Shows suggested queries related to the user's search query. Activate the Search Server Web Part feature.

Search Action Links:
Shows search action links (used in search results page).

Search Best Bets:
Shows the best bet items that match the search query.

Search Box:
Search input box.

Search Core Results:
Main search results (used in search results page).

Search Paging:
Paging control to navigate between pages of search results. Used in conjunction with search results web part.

Search Statistics:
Shows search statistics including the total number of results found and the time taken to perform the search.

Search Summary:
Shows suggestions related to the current search query.

Top Federated Results:
Shows the highest ranking results from a federated search provider.

XSLT List View:
Renders a SharePoint list using an XSLT transformation. This can be configured either by creating an XSLT stylesheet or using SharePoint Designer. The XSLTListViewer web part is used as the basis of the web parts for showing common lists in a site, e.g. Announcements, Links and Tasks.

Search Visual Best Bet:
Shows the best bet items by means of thumbnails of the content of the target documents.

Filter Actions:
Use this web part when you have two or more filter web parts on the page in order to synchronize the display of the filter results.

Note Board:
Allow users to leave brief text notes about the page.

Organization Browser:
Shows an organization chart based on the user profile data.

What's New:
Shows a list of colleagues and status changes in a My Site profile page.

Wherabouts:
Shows user's locations from the user profile data.

XSLT List Form:
Used to render a list view with in-place editing enabled.

Wiki Content:
Renders a wiki control, similar to the Wiki Editor field control.

Chart View:
Used to render a survey as a histogram. Not a general purpose charting component (see Chart web part).

Data View:
Query data and render using XSLT. Intended to be used with SharePoint Designer.

Data Form:
Renders an input form.

Dual Chinese Search:
Used to search Dual Chinese document and items at the same time. Activate the Search Server Web Part feature.

My Mail Folder:
Displays your mail folder using Outlook Web Access for Microsoft Exchange Server.

My Calendar:
Displays your calendar using Outlook Web Access for Microsoft Exchange Server

My Contacts:
Displays your contacts using Outlook Web Access for Microsoft Exchange Server

My Inbox:
Displays your inbox using Outlook Web Access for Microsoft Exchange Server

My Tasks:
Displays your tasks using Outlook Web Access for Microsoft Exchange Server

WSRP Viewer:
Displays portlets from web sites using WSRP 1.1. Web Services for Remote Portlets is an OASIS network protocol standard designed for communications with remote portlets.

User Context Filter:
The UserContextFilter web part is used to filter other web parts based on a property of the current user. Usually this will be the current user ID, but it could also be any user profile property; e.g. Name, Department, Email, etc.